# How can I make the same links to send to instant messengers?

Tags: html, css, django

I started writing my website on Django and today I finally launched it on VPS. I sent the link to a friend and realized that it didn’t look good enough.

I have

[my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqPq0.png)

like what i want result

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVpky.png)

I tried adding meta tags to HTML:

```
            <meta property="og:title" content=" MySite ">
            <meta property="og:site_name" content="ORXM Until">
            <meta property="og:locale" content="ru_RU">
            <meta property="og:type" content="website">
```

Comment: You probably should add a description and image of the open-graph.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem Can you tell me in more detail what you mean, I don’t fully understand